# Correct way to use INNER JOIN statement using a bridge table

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Basically I have a table "Products" with "Product_ID" and table "Sub_Categories" with "Sub_Category_ID".

Products that have a "Sub_Category" are linked using a bridge table, "SubC_Prod_Bridge", they are linked by ID "Products" and "Sub_Category_ID".

Like this:

```
Table: Products
Product_ID
4

Table: Sub_Categories
Sub_Category_ID
5

Table: SubC_Prod_Bridge
Product_ID   Sub_Category_ID
4            5
```

I know this question is very basic. What I am really looking for is a good reference online for JOIN statements, any recommendations are really appreciated.

Comment: My favorite site for explaining joins [site](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Fantastic. That's what I'm talking about!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
SELECT P.*, S.*
FROM Products P
JOIN SubC_Prod_Bridge B
  ON P.Product_ID = B.Product_ID
JOIN Sub_Categories S
  ON S.Sub_Category_ID = B.Sub_Category_ID
```